# Access data / functions from several view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, class, delegates

I am trying to build an app with several screens. Every screen should have different buttons which all call one function.

My problem is that I do not understand how to call one function from different view controllers with input parameters.
Also I want to have another variable defined accessible and changeable from every view controller.

This is what I kind of want my code to be:

```
import UIKit


var address = "address"


public func makeRequest(Command: String){
    
     let url = URL(address + Command)

     print(url)
    

}







class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        

        let command = "command"
        
        makeRequest(Command: command)

        
    }


}



class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("address")

       address = "address2"

    


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all classes are view controllers put the method in an extension of `UIViewController` and the address constant in a struct

```
struct Constant {
    static let address = "address"
}

extension UIViewController {

    public func makeRequest(command: String) -> URL? {
        guard let url = URL(string: Constant.address + command) else { return nil }
        print(url)
        return url
    }
}
```

Comment: The declaration of "url"  causes an error: "Non-void function should return a value"

Comment: Please see the edit

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UIViewController{
        func getName(name: String)-> String{
            print("hai \(name)")
            return name
        }
    }
```

you can write a extension for Viewcontroller and try to call the method like this. if you write the extension for viewcontroller you can directly call them with its reference

```
self.getName(name:"Raghav")
```